# Is it true that only probabilistic trajectories can be consistent with special relativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

The paper, "[Quantum principle of relativity](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/ab76f7/pdf)" by Dragan and Ekert is not very rigorous, but does make some interesting points.

The point that caught my interest is that probabilistic trajectories can be consistent with full-blown special relativity that includes superluminal solutions, whereas deterministic trajectories cannot generally be consistent in that context.

Is that specific point correct?

Comment: My understanding is that reviews of papers is off-topic, but maybe someone can clarify that.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure offhand, but I believe you're correct @StephenG. Asking a specific question about some particular concept in a paper is on topic, of course, but a general review of the paper or some similarly broad question, like this one, I think is off topic.

Comment: I have narrowed the question in response to the comments.

Comment: @DavidZ, I'm looking for the private feedback, but haven't found it.

Comment: @S.McGrew What private feedback are you referring to?

Comment: Supposedly when a question is closed, there is private feedback.

Comment: Not as far as I know. The only feedback you get _automatically_ is what you see on the question page itself - of course you can always request additional feedback in the comments or [chat]. If you know and can link to where you read about this private feedback, I'd encourage posting to ask about it on [meta], and maybe we can clarify what it's talking about.